# Drop NA Values with SAS

Tags: excel, sas

I have an `xlsx` file that I wish to delete the `NA` values in `SAS`. I'm new to `SAS`, how do I do this?
[image]

Comment: By “Delete the NA values” you mean observations ? You can delete all the missing observations but not the values ... in your dataset if you drop all observations that has 1+ missing that you loose almost all the data ... better is to impute the missing.

Answer (score 1):

> For numeric data(observations) in order to drop you can use `missing` and `delete`:

```
data olddata;
set cleandata;
if missing(coalesce(of _numeric_)) then delete;run;
```

*Note: untested code*